# JASidePanelController and update switch state in center view controller after turning off a switch in left view controller

Tags: ios, uiswitch

in my app I've implemented JASidePanelController, it works great. My app is so: in center view controller I've the main window, in which you can read some information about the next TV show and put a local notification to notify when your favorite TV show is starting. In my left view controller I've a table view in which you can find all TV shows and you can put a local notification for remind you when the TV show is starting. My issue is when I set the notification in center view controller I can update the switch for that show in the table view of the left notification, but I can't understand how to update the switch in the center view controller, for example:
I set a notification for next TV show in center view controller, when I swipe right to see the left view controller, the switch for the next show is enabled. When I delete notification in table view of the left view controller, the switch in the center view controller doesn't change his state. How can I solve this issue? Can you give me any suggestion to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key Value Observing(KVO): allows any object to observe a property of another object which the observing object is notified when that property’s value changes. It learns about the new value as well as the old one. It helps apps become more cohesive by by keeping objects in the model, controller, and view layers synchronized to changes

[Introduction to KVO link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)